# VS2019 - Xamarin - iOS - MacInCloud - Cannot Set Up Provisioning Profile - No Current IOS devices

Tags: ios, iphone, visual-studio, xamarin, mac-in-cloud

1. Pair to the MacInCloud (I have the Managed Server Plan).
2. iOS Bundle Signing
3. Automatic Provisioning
4. Choose my Team (Creates Certificate, Identifier and Tries to Create the Device
5. It cannot find the device. On MacIncloud I run

xcrun simctl list | egrep '(Booted)'

6. Find the UUID of my iPhone Simulator
7. Go to developer.apple.com
8. Try to add Provisioning Profile. Add the this device it will only recognize the UUID as a Mac.
9. Go back to VS 2019 and "retry"

Error:  There were errors in the data supplied. Please correct and re-submit. There are no current IOS devices on this team matching the provided device IDs.

I have no clue how to add the MacInCloud or the iPhone Simulator on the MacInCloud.

TIA

Comment: You do not create a provisioning profile for simulators, just use manual provisioning with your developer identity

Comment: You can only add UDIDs of real iOS devices and you can't create a provisioning profile without at least one real UDID in your account

Comment: Ugh. STILL NOT FIXED. I changed to Manual Provisioning and Developer Automatic - same error message. Then I changed to my Apple Development Signing Identity. Same Error Message. Could not find any available provisioning profiles.

Comment: I tried building again and it worked.  So...@Paulw11 can I eventually put my app on the Itunes with MacInCloud?